# Can you find the answer to this algebra equation?

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

This is an old favorite of mine...

Can you find the answer?

$(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(d-x)...(z-x)=?$

Comment: I am damn sure that this is a duplicate question. I have seen the same question here at the early stages of the puzzling.stackexchange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer:

> $0$

Reasoning:

> As $(x-x)=0$ and $0$ multiplied by any number is $0$.

Comment: Oh you posted just seconds before I did. I'll remove my answer.